# Some links not working due to X-Frame-Options

Tags: html, iframe, x-frame-options

I am hosting a webpage created using Dreamweaver CS6 via Apache. When certain links are clicked, they will not load. Inspecting element in Chrome reveals the following error for one of the non-working links:

> Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yA-Eb_PD4SQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Interestingly, if one right clicks and opens the link in a new tab or window, it will load. FYI I know very little about html and CSS.

*Edit for clarification: how to I tell my site or Apache not to open these links in frames so they will work?

Comment: Probably more on topic at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: I'm hosting the site at home, so the question wouldn't be welcome at serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Google (and therefore also YouTube) specifically block you from `iframe`ing its websites.

The error message is rather self-explanatory.

More info: [MDN - The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Also, there's plenty more information on Stack Overflow if you search for [x-frame-options sameorigin](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=x-frame-options%20sameorigin%20is%3aquestion).

Comment: The link you posted to MDN concerns allowing others to open your content in iframes. The search you suggested returns mostly threads started by people who want to somehow force others' content to open in iframes. I don't want to do either. I don't even really know what an iframe is. I just want the links to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you're using for your links. You must be using `iframe`s.